# Combining 2 producer requests with overlapping time frames into one and returning 2 original requests

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We can have multiple producers that will request the same data but with a different time range. Ex. All downtime for a machine between Jan 1st 2019 and Feb 1st 2019. The other producer is asking for all downtime for the same machine but for Jan 15th 2019 to Mar 31st 2019.

I would like to combine into 1 request from Jan 1st 2019 to Mar 31st 2019 while returning the original request result to each of them.

We are able to send the 2 requests individually through kafka, retrieve the data and consume the results by the same producer that asked for it.

We are currently looking at Ktables , Kafka stream and Kafka api to be able to achieve our goal of combining our time range request.

Was not able to test it yet

Comment: (1) Producers write data into Kafka topics -- hence, not sure what you mean by "producers _request_ data"? (2) It's unclear where the data is stored? In Kafka? Or in some other symstem and you want to write the data into Kafka (you talk about producers). (3) Kafka topics are consumer in offset order -- you cannot range-query Kafka topics on time.

Comment: Hi Matthias, Thank you for the comment. I forgot that Kafka do not understand the message but only receive and send it. I will look at the api to see if I can (in some cases , combine 2 request for the same key-value stream) and send the response back to both Producer (request the data). Thank again for the clarification and the quick response